# Second-countable, analytic, completely Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category, polish-spaces

First a few definitions. A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be:

- a Polish space if it is separable and completely metrizable.
- Analytic, if there exists a surjective continuous map from a (Borel subset of) Polish space to the space $X$.
- Completely Baire (some say "hereditarily Baire"), if each closed subspace is Baire

Now my question is: do we have a counterexample of a **non**-Polish space that is analytic, second-countable, and completely Baire? Can we say at least that the existence of such counterexample is consistent with ZFC?

Thanks

Comment: I feel like you mean to include more hypotheses (some separation axiom?) to rule out some trivial examples.  For instance, every non-discrete finite topological space...

Comment: @EricWofsey well, we can require the space to be uncountable...

Comment: That doesn't really help.  You can take an indiscrete space of cardinality continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper of Medini and Zdomskyy provides an answer: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7899.pdf

They prove that you can't have a counterexample of a coanalytic separable metric space, and that this extends to projective spaces under projective determinacy. They also prove that it is consistent with ZFC that there is an analytic counterexample.